# Android :How to parse data from server into JSON? Do I need to write a file and where do I store this file?

Tags: android

I have read questions available on forum but I am still confused. Is it possible to read app's data from server using JSON? App data is available from server in HTML form. How to parse this html webpage into JSON? Where to store JSON parsing file(I mean in which folder). I'm not using wordpress/cms for blog/data. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You usually do not read data from a server in HTML format. HTML is used to display something in a browser or in a WebView. For data, you use either JSON or XML, where JSON is the standard these days. So you server has to provide a service that returns JSON. There might be some cases where you want to read HTML, but you would not parse it into JSON. There is no point in doing so. You had to read it as XML and find the data you are interested in. The problem with that approach is that HTML is often not well formed - not every opening tag has a corresponding closing tag. While browsers are fine with that, XML parser are usually not and your app will crash.